# Autoit install whit Python 2.7 and Windows 64 bit

Tags: python, django, autoit

I tried to install autoit like documentation:

```
pip install -U pyautoit
```

But got 32-bit error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

How do I install it on 64 bit?

TY

Comment: The package hasn't been updated in years. Which version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your windows version is 64 version, there is some error if you install directly. just follow the below instruction.
first you need to download autoit zip file ,then unzip it. you need to change something in autoit.py
in line 15,change dll = "AutoItX3.dll" to dll = "AutoItX3_x64.dll", then use python setup.py install , you will succeed

from:https://github.com/jacexh/pyautoit/issues/24